# Bolzano theorem application

Tags: real-analysis

let $f: [0, 1] \to [0,1]$ continuous function. Show that there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ so that $f(x_0)=1-x_0$.

I tried to draw a picture so I could understand it better, do I need to create a function $g$ to do something with $f$?

Comment: Can you prove that $f$ intersects the function $g(x)=1-x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x):=f(x)-1+x$. Then $h(0)=f(0)-1 \le 0$ and $h(1)=f(1) \ge 0$

Bolzano says: there is $x_0 \in [0,1]$ wit $h(x_0)=0$

Answer (score 0):

By Brower fixed point theorem, there exist point $x_0$ for which is $g(x_0)=x_0$, where $g(x)=1-f(x):[0,1]\to [0,1]$.

This holds since $h(x)=g(x)-x:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ has zero in interval $[0,1]$, because $h(0)\geq 0$ and $h(1)\leq 0$.